# how to name items in a string group?

Tags: c#, string

Say

```
string[] strGroup=returnStr.split(',');
```

How to name each item of **strGroup**, if it has a meaning list of each item? So when I need to use a specific item I just use `strGroup["LastName"]` instead of `strGroup[23]`.

Comment: But where are the names defined for your string? Is this a CSV file with first row containing columns names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to be looking at a dictionary of strings.

```
string[] data = returnStr.Split(',');
var map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
map["LastName"] = data[23];
map["FirstName"] = data[24]; // or whatever
```

Now use the map rather than the string array.

```
string firstName = map["FirstName"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (crazy LINQ talk, I know)

```
string returnStr = "Claus,Junker,Jørgensen";

string[] keys = new string[]
{
    "FirstName",
    "MiddleName",
    "LastName"
};

Dictionary<string, string> groups = returnStr.Split(',')
         .Select((x, i) => Tuple.Create(keys[i], x))
         .ToDictionary(k => k.Item1, v => v.Item2);

// Alternative version

Dictionary<string, string> groups = returnStr.Split(',')
         .Zip(keys, (k, v) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k, v))
         .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Comment: Uh.. this will be a very brittle parsing logic.

Comment: Yes, of course it will. But such a crazy question deserves a crazy answer :p

Comment: Too bad, I use .NET 3.5 which does not support Tuple. Your code is very neat, superb.I'm still trying to understand.Thanks.

Comment: See alternative version for non-tuple'd version.

Answer (score 2):

An array does not have a string [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), so this is not possible as such.

You will need to define a name for each part of your string - `Split` will not do that for you.

You *could* use a structure that has a defined string [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), but you will still need to define the key for each item.

There is no magical way that this definition will occur, unless you *do* have the meta data for each field, somewhere. For example, some CSV parsers will produce such a collection by using the first row as field names.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to use `split` to read a CSV file/stream.

What you can do is store the first line in an array, using split and then, while iterating the lines withing the file, you can reference like this:

```
string[] strGroup=returnStr.split(',');
var someThing = strGroup[GetIndex("LastName")];
```

and define `GetIndex` like this:

```
public int GetIndex(string str)
{
    return Array.IndexOf<string>(headerArray, str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see alot of Dictionary examples, but if you are embedding knowledge about the row format in your code, why not make a class of it? Use the constructor to turn `returnStr` into properties:

```
class Group
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set;}
    public string LastName { get; private set;}
    [...]

    public Group(string returnStr)
    {
        string[] strGroup=returnStr.split(',');
        [...]
        this.FirstName = strGroup[22];
        this.LastName = strGroup[23];
        [...]
    }
 }
```

With this approach, you won't have to maintain a set of string constants. If that is a win or not depends on your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class is for. In your case you need a `Dictionary<string,string>`. However you'll have to initialize it once before you can access items via their name.

Answer (score 0):

When you have only one string use the `Dictionary<string, string>` datatype.

When you have a whole list of splitted strings, use DataTable and use column names.